# Why does gettext Automake macros include deprecated AM_PROG_MKDIR_P macro?

Tags: gnome, automake

I'm trying to build a project of mine I haven't revisited in a while. I uses the GNU autotools in the fashion typical for GNOME application.  Now, when running `autogen.sh` (which, in turn uses `gnome-autogen.sh`) I get the following error:

```
automake: warnings are treated as errors
configure.ac:47: warning: The 'AM_PROG_MKDIR_P' macro is deprecated, and its use is discouraged.
configure.ac:47: You should use the Autoconf-provided 'AC_PROG_MKDIR_P' macro instead,
configure.ac:47: and use '$(MKDIR_P)' instead of '$(mkdir_p)'in your Makefile.am files.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
[simon:~/git/toddlerfun] master(+2/-2) 1 ±
```

The problem seems to originate from gettext, running the commands from [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709740]) gives the same results:

```
$ grep -ri AM_PROG_MKDIR_P m4
m4/intl.m4:  AC_REQUIRE([AM_PROG_MKDIR_P])dnl defined by automake
m4/po.m4:  AC_REQUIRE([AM_PROG_MKDIR_P])dnl defined by automake
$ head -n1 m4/po.m4 m4/intl.m4
==> m4/po.m4 <==
# po.m4 serial 17 (gettext-0.18)

==> m4/intl.m4 <==
# intl.m4 serial 17 (gettext-0.18)
```

However, reading further on [that bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709740), this is supposed to be fixed in gettext 0.18.2.  And the version on my Ubuntu 14.10 is 0.19:

```
$ gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.19.2
```

So why is not the correct, bug-fixed macro installed?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this while writing the question. You need to make sure that the right version of the macro is included from `configure.ac`.  I had:

```
AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION([0.18])
```

Upgrading to:

```
AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION([0.19])
```

Made things work. Posting this answer so that others who might have similar problems could maybe get help.